# Need help on navigation errors on react native app

Tags: react-native

I keep getting an error when trying to navigate to Home after register and login. This is the error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator. This is how I am navigating to Home after registration: navigation.navigate("Home");

Would love some advice or guidance.

```
function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


function ProfileStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function LeaderboardStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="LeaderboardScreen" component={LeaderboardScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const getPage = (user) => {

  if (user) {
    return (
      <>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: () => {
            if (route.name == "Home") {
              return <Entypo name="home" size={24} color="black" />;
            } else if (route.name == "Leaderboard") {
              return (
                <MaterialIcons name="leaderboard" size={24} color="black" />
              );
            } else if (route.name == "Profile") {
              return (
                <Ionicons name="person-circle" size={24} color="black" />
              );
            }
          },
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeStack}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: "Home" }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Leaderboard"
          component={LeaderboardStack}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: "Leaderboard" }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileStack}
          options={{ tabBarLabel: "Profile" }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      </>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
     </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }
}

export default function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users");
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data();
            setLoading(false);
            setUser(userData);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {getPage(user)}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things happening here, sorry to say but your coding is mess, i can give you example how can manage it cleanly, however all i can see herr is that you tab which contains your homestack and a screen you put in stack above tab both have the same name "Home" change your stack name with homestack and try navigating there..